# Is v8/firefox RegExp implementation based on finite automata or recursive backtrace?

Tags: javascript, regex, v8, finite-automata

I came across this document: https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html
That claims that Perl, Java and many other languages use "slow" RegExp based on recursive backtrace, but grep and awk (also Go) use much faster finite automata. I.e. regexp are converted to FA and then executed. The paper also claims that all languages should just switch to FA technique, although its implementation is more complex. I am curious if current JavaScript implementations have it one way or another.

Comment: JS regex is [more like Perl](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10), but it does not mean the engine is "slow". Note that the pattern used in that article is too artificial, `a?a?a?aaa` must be written as `a{3,6}` and it is as fast as can be. It is just a kind of an example of how bad patterns may slow down the regex execution. If you write patterns correctly and for the "right" task, you won't have much trouble with regex in any language.

Comment: not really a coding question is it ... anyone can search for and find the source code to V8 and SpiderMonkey (firefox's current JS engine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

V8's regexp engine "Irregexp" is based on automata, see https://blog.chromium.org/2009/02/irregexp-google-chromes-new-regexp.html.

Firefox nowadays uses a fork of V8's Irregexp, see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=976446, so it is based on automata as well.

Comment: For the record, Irregexp is backtracking based. The compiler may try to build a an automaton and optimize it, but at the end, it generates code that does backtracking. When lucky, it can optimize or omit some backtracks that it can see won't be necessary.